# Magento Order Products Calculation Missing

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, error, products, order-email

The customer added 17 products to their cart as well as placed the order and the admin also received 17 products order.

**The issue:** The amount was calculated for only one product and confirmation mail was also sent regarding only one product.

**Screen Shots:**

Admin Received Order:

[image]

The order mail sent to customer with only one product in order,

[image]

**Note : The amount consuming for only one product cost. How to solve this error.
       Order Mismatching of products?**